C How to hold off a thread while stepper motor is running
I have CMSIS RTOS running on an ARM controller. One thread is used for executing stepper motor movements.
The stepper motor moves 2000 steps in one direction and returns to the startpoint.
Currently, after executing the run command, the thread is prevented from executing the returnCommand() function by a loop. The loop is ended by a flag that is set by a stepcounter which is called by an interrupt.
I tried to solve the blocking using a mutex, but either I didn't understand the function correctly or implemented it incorrectly.
Old code:
void stepperMotor_thread(void *arg)
{
  runCommand();
  while(!movementDone)
  {
    osDelay(100);
  }
  returnCommand();
}

void exti_handler()
{
  if (stepsreached)
  {
    stopCommand();
    movementDone = true;
  }
}

New code:
osMutexId move_Mutex_ID;

const osMutexAttr_t Thread_Mutex_attr = {
    "myThreadMutex",    // Human readable mutex name
    osMutexPrioInherit, // Attr_bits
    NULL,               // Memory for control block
    0U                  // Size for control block
};

void stepperMotor_thread(void *arg)
{
  move_Mutex_ID = osMutexNew(&Thread_Mutex_attr);
  runCommand();
  osMutexAcquire(move_Mutex_ID, osWaitForever);
  returnCommand();
}

void exti_handler()
{
  steps++;
  if (stepsreached())
  {
    stopCommand();
    osMutexRelease(move_Mutex_ID);
  }
}


I honestly don't understand what you're asking for. Formally, there is no question. Also, it's unclear what the observed behaviour for the two code snippets is and what the expected behaviour is in contrast. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

I didn't fully understand expected behaviour but in the first code if you can use semaphore to lazy wait until interrupt happens.

IDK about CMSIS or whatever RTOS you are using, but in many libraries and operating systems, if a thing is called "mutex," then you must not ever unlock it in a different thread from the one that locked it. Often, there is a different thing called "semaphore" that allows you to do what you're trying to do (e.g., like in Savrona's answer).

Mutexes are used for synchronizing access to a shared resource between threads: acquire the mutex, do something with the resource, release the mutex. Since at most one thread can hold the mutex at any given time, if multiple threads try to acquire it, one succeeds and the others have to wait -- thus, the shared resource is ever only used by one thread. Semaphores or condition variables are used to communicate between threads.

In older code : stepsreached is not incremented. This implies 'movementDone' never becomes true and your code gets stuck in while(!movementDone) loop.

I am not quite sure if this is what you want to achieve.
osSemaphoreId_t movementSemaphore;
const osSemaphoreAttr_t movementSemaphoreAttr = {
    .name = "MovementSemaphore"
};

// Create the semaphore with an initial count of 0 (not available)
movementSemaphore = osSemaphoreNew(1, 0, &movementSemaphoreAttr);

void stepperMotor_thread(void *arg)
{
    runCommand();

    // Wait indefinitely for the semaphore to be signaled
    osSemaphoreAcquire(movementSemaphore, osWaitForever);

    returnCommand();
}

void exti_handler()
{
    if (stepsreached)
    {
        stopCommand();
        osSemaphoreRelease(movementSemaphore); // Signal the semaphore
    }
}


Mutex semaphores must be acquired and released by the same thread (and cannot be acquired in an interrupt thread).
For inter-process synchronisation use a binary semaphore (implemented using a counting semaphore with a max count of 1 in CMSIS RTOS), or more simply in this case a task event.

You really want a condition variable. A condition variable allows a thread to sleep waiting for a condition to be met.
See the following:
Using condition variables
CMSIS RTOS may not have a condition variable construct. You could probably use osSignalWait(). See CMSIS Introduction.
Another option supported by CMSIS RTOS is osMutexWait(). This is likely the most reasonable way to go for your use case. Using condition variables

The last two links seem to be effectively broken. It may be some kind of redirect (though the URLs do not change).


Currently, after executing the run command, the thread is prevented from executing the returnCommand() function by a loop. The loop is ended by a flag that is set by a stepcounter which is called by an interrupt.

The way of doing this is to put the thread to wait on some event (cond_t variable) and to wake up the thread when the interrupt arrives. When the thread is scheduled, it will have to check if the event arrived, and go to wait again if not (disable interrupts, check if the event was received, release the event, enable interrupts, wait again)
Or if the interrupt handler is just incrementing the counter, awake the thread and return from the interrupt after the increment.  Once the thread is awaken, it must just check if the counter has been incremented.  Well it depends on how you want the thread to wait, and the API you have to sleep for an event.
A wakeup() never blocks, so it can be executed in a signal handler, You need to recheck the condition, because normally the wakeup() wakes up all threads related to the event... and the first to get it gets the event, while others normally have to go to sleep again until the next event arrives... or not, that depends on how you make your event handler.
